# SQL Query to find whether a entry if greater than sum of average of whole column +standard deviation of whole column

Tags: mysql, sql, average, standard-deviation

Let's say I have a table with

| student | Marks |
| --- | --- |
| john | 30 |
| ron | 40 |

I have to write a query which gives me output as student name and avg(marks column)+standardeviation(marks column) or 0 , if student marks is greater than avg(marks column)+standardeviation(marks column) then avg(marks column)+standardeviation(marks column) else 0

I have written a query but it does not work

```
select student, case when marks>(select avg(marks)+stddev_pop(marks) from students) then  avg(marks column)+standardeviation(marks column) when  marks=(select avg(marks)+stddev_pop(marks) then marks else 0 end as final_marks from students
```

Please can anyone suggest any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  Use window functions.  And in MySQL, you don't need a `case` because booleans are supported:

```
select s.student,
       (s.marks > avg(s.marks) over () + stddev_pop(s.marks) over ()) as final_marks
from students s;
```

In older versions of MySQL, I would recommend a subquery in the `from` clause:

```
select s.*,
       (s.marks > ss.avg_marks + ss.stddev_pop_marks) as final_marks
from students s cross join
     (select avg(s.marks) as avg_marks,
             stddev_pop(s.marks) as stddev_pop_marks
      from students
     ) ss
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , if instead of 1 i have to insert avg(marks column)+standardeviation(marks column)  then how should I modify my query

Comment: @rinkinag . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  A new question should be asked as *new* question.  However, if you just want an additional column with the overall average + standard deviation, then it should be clear how to add that in either of these solutions.